# WinRT - consume WCF service

Tags: wcf, windows-runtime, named-pipes

I have a windows service, which acts as a propagator for data received from external source. This windows service hosts WCF `ServiceHost` with `NetNamedPipeBinding()`. `ServiceContract` also defines `CallbackContract`

There is also a client DLL component, which consumes the server and bubbles up parsed data as an event.  Data is bubbled upon receiving callback from the server.

The code works in desktop app, however when I try to reference client DLL in WinRT app I get following error:

`The pipe name could not be obtained for the pipe URI: Access is denied. (5, 0x5)`

I presume this is because WinRT (to my knowledge) lacks support for named pipes.

How to go about consuming such service in WinRT? I can alter WCF side to any requirement, but it has to be hosted as windows service (it has non WinRT consumers). Communication will always occur within the same machine, polling is the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to switch to `basicHttpBinding`, because net.namedpipe is not supported.

Actually supported are BasicHttpBinding, NetTcpBinding, NetHttpBinding

Secondly in WinRT there's a policy in place, which prevents you from accessing *localhost* over the network stack.

To overcome this security policy you need to add a LoopbackExempt for your app.

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -s
```

See details on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx

For the duplex way either POLLING is an aption (only works, when the app is focused).

Or using push notifications: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/10/15/windows-8-notifications-push-notifications.aspx

Comment: `bassicHttpBinding` doesn't support duplex message exchange pattern, or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh.. and by the way.. Due to the nature of WinRT you should better use Push Notifications instead of the polling anyway!

Comment: Have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/10/15/windows-8-notifications-push-notifications.aspx for push notifications.

Comment: Looks promising, however this approach would require major overhaul of existing service, which is a project in its own rights.

Comment: @StaWho Regarding the LoopbackExempt: it's meant only for development purposes, so that you can have the service and the app running on the same computer. Windows Store apps are only allowed to access services on other computers when they are deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HttpClient class.. that's the only simple workaround, and works as well.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP");
var soapXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><GetCityWeatherByZIP xmlns=\"http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/\"><ZIP>23454</ZIP></GetCityWeatherByZIP></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
var response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx", new StringContent(soapXml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")).Result;
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Try this? I hope this is what you're looking for - https://quirkd.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/shorts-consuming-a-wcf-asmx-web-service-in-winrt/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok, done.. :) thanks for the suggestion, though the link is to my own blog, and is less likely to change.

Comment: Perhaps you can also include a short snippet of code that demonstrates the usage of this class. You don't have to excerpt your entire post - as that would defeat the purpose of having a blog in the first place - but we'd like for answers to stand on their own as much as possible, with links provided more as supplementary reading.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I'm new here!